# Restoring Lightsail snapshot to a different region

Tags: redirect, amazon-lightsail

I copied an instance snapshot image from region A to region B. From region B I then create a new instance using that snapshot. However, when I navigate to the public IP address in the region B instance it redirects me to the public IP address of region A (where the snapshot was originally created).

Is this expected behaviour? And how can I avoid this redirect?

Comment: Are you sure that lightsail is doing the redirection? What are you actually running on the instance? Does it have a redirect statement that is actually kicking in?

I did a simple experiment where I created a PHP website that just echos the host IP. I created the snapshot, moved it to a new region, and deployed a new instance. 

The new instance doesn't do any redirection, and displays the IP of the new instance, which leads me to believe this isn't a Lightsail issue (or if it it is, it's a bug and we'll want to get it looked at).

Comment: Thanks for testing this.
I'm just running a WordPress instance on lightsail which is now inaccessible (due to redirecting to the old IP).
I'm not sure exactly where the redirection is happening. I don't have any dns redirection setup on lightsail.

Comment: I believe that there are some configurations settings within WP itself that deal with the base URL  for the server. I suspect that is where this is happening. 

Let me play with it a bit and see what I can find out.